# Has Post request a limited number of parameters?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to send to my server 5 parameters:

1. **Action**: will contain the **name of the form**, in this case "**signin**"
2. Name: Name of the person who wants to signin
3. Surname: Surname of the person who wants to signin
4. Email: Email of the person who wants to signin
5. Password: Password of the person who wants to signin

the problem is that my server reads only 4 parameters: Name, Surname, Email and Password, and it don't see Action!

Here's the code:

**Javascript:**

```
function signin() {
    alert("OK");
    var action = $(this).attr('name'); // puts in action the name of the form (this case "signin")
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: {
            Action: action, // the server don't see it!!
            Name: document.getElementById('signin-name').value, // Name in the form
            Surname: document.getElementById('signin-surname').value, // // Surname in the form
            Email: document.getElementById('singin-email').value, // Email in the form
            Password: document.getElementById('singin-password').value // // Password in the form
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
            alert("success");
            window.location.href = "index.php"; // load the index.php page, which contains the login form
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP - Signin.php:**

```
<!-- Signin Form -->

<?php
require('include/header.php');
?>

<div class="limiter">
    <div class="form-container">
        <div class="form-wrap">
            <form action="submit.php" method="post" name="form-signin" id="form-signin" autocomplete="off">

                <span class="form-title">Registration form</span>

                <div class="form-field">
                    <label for="Name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Name" id="signin-name" class="form-control" required pattern=".{1,100}" autofocus>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <label for="Surname">Surname</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Surname" id="signin-surname" class="form-control" required pattern=".{1,100}" autofocus>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="Email" id="signin-email" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <label for="Password">New password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="Password" id="signin-password" placeholder="Almeno 6 caratteri" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div id="display-error" class="alert alert-danger fade in"></div><!-- Display Error Container -->



                <div class="form-submit-container">
                    <div class="form-submit-wrap">
                        <button class="form-cancel-button" type="submit">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="form-submit-button" type="submit" onclick="signin()">Signin</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php require('include/footer.php');?>
```

**PHP - Submit.php:**

```
<?php

#Detect AJAX and POST request, if is empty exit
if((empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') or empty($_POST)){
    exit("Unauthorized Acces");
}

require('inc/config.php');
require('inc/functions.php');

# Check if Login form is submitted
if(!empty($_POST) && $_POST['Action'] === 'form-login'){

    # Define return variable. for further details see "output" function in functions.php
    $Return = array('result'=>array(), 'error'=>'');

    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];

    /* Server side PHP input validation */
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $Return['error'] = "Please enter a valid Email address.";
    } else if($password === '') {
        $Return['error'] = "Please enter Password.";
    }
    if($Return['error']!='') {
        output($Return);
    }

    # Checking Email and Password existence in DB

    # Selecting the email address of the user with the correct login credentials.
    $query = $db->query("SELECT Email FROM USERS WHERE Email='$email' AND Password='$password'");
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($query->rowCount() == 1) {
        # Success: Set session variables and redirect to Protected page
        $Return['result'] = $_SESSION['UserData'] = $result;
    } else {
        # Failure: Set error message
        $Return['error'] = 'Invalid Login Credential.';
    }

    output($Return);
}

# Check if Registration form is submitted
if(!empty($_POST) && $_POST['Action'] === 'form-signin') {

    # Define return variable. for further details see "output" function in functions.php
    $Return = array('result'=>array(), 'error'=>'');

    $name = $_POST['Name'];
    $surname = $_POST['Surname'];
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];

    # Server side PHP input validation
    if($name === '') {
        $Return['error'] = "Please enter Full name.";
    } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $Return['error'] = "Please enter a valid Email address.";
    } else if($password === '') {
        $Return['error'] = "Please enter Password.";
    }
    if($Return['error']!='') {
        output($Return);
    }

    # Check Email existence in DB
    $result = $db->query("SELECT Email FROM USERS WHERE Name='$name' AND Surname='$surname' AND Email='$email'");
    if($result->rowCount() == 1){
        # Email already exists: Set error message
        $Return['error'] = 'You have already registered with us, please login.';
    }else{
        # Insert the new user data inside the DB
        try{
            $db->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`ID_user`, `Name`, `Surname`, `Email`, `Password`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$surname', '$email', '$password')");
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        # Success: Set session variables and redirect to Protected page
        $Return['result'] = $_SESSION['UserData'] = $result;
    }

    output($Return);
}
```

**PHP - Functions.php**

```
# Function to set JSON output
function output($Return=array()){
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    #exit(json_encode($Return)); # Final JSON response
    echo json_encode($Return);
}
```

here is a screenshot of the debugger:
[Debug Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dng7J.png)

Comment: By 'dont see it', do you mean the variable is not even existing in $_POST, or its there, but empty.

Comment: It definitely <b>isn't</b> a post data argument limit issue. You could send much longer forms in. Somewhere something else is breaking. Could you open up the deveoloperTools/network tab and review the request that is being sent from the client side? To make sure the "Action" field is being sent.

Comment: why aren't you using a prepared statement?

Comment: @IncredibleHat by "don't see it" I mean this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dng7J.png

Comment: Ok, it doesnt even exist in the $_POST. You could have just said that instead of post an image ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function signin() {
    alert("OK");
    var action = $('#form-signin').attr('name'); // puts in action the name of the form (this case "signin")
    
  //  alert(action);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: {
            Action: action, // the server don't see it!!
            Name: $('signin-name').val(), // Name in the form
            Surname: $('signin-surname').val(), // // Surname in the form
            Email: $('singin-email').val(), // Email in the form
            Password: $('singin-password').val() // // Password in the form
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
            alert("success");
            window.location.href = "index.php"; // load the index.php page, which contains the login form
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="limiter">
    <div class="form-container">
        <div class="form-wrap">
            <form action="submit.php" method="post" name="form-signin" id="form-signin" autocomplete="off">

                <span class="form-title">Registration form</span>

                <div class="form-field">
                    <label for="Name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Name" id="signin-name" class="form-control" required pattern=".{1,100}" autofocus>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <label for="Surname">Surname</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Surname" id="signin-surname" class="form-control" required pattern=".{1,100}" autofocus>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="Email" id="signin-email" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <label for="Password">New password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="Password" id="signin-password" placeholder="Almeno 6 caratteri" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div id="display-error" class="alert alert-danger fade in"></div><!-- Display Error Container -->



                <div class="form-submit-container">
                    <div class="form-submit-wrap">
                        <button class="form-cancel-button" type="submit">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="form-submit-button" type="submit" onclick="signin()">Signin</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LorenzoTabasso i add some modification  to your code. can you try it??

Comment: That's not necessary anymore, I changed at all, and now works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your scope for `$this`. Since your Javascript is called within a `BUTTON` element, `$this` has a scope relative to the button, not the form. In trying to check what `$this` returns by itself, it says `[object Window]`.

```
function signin() {
 console.log(this);
}

Console:
[object Window]
```

You need to either pass `this` via `signin(this)` and backtrack to the containing `form` element if you plan on reusing the Javascript for other forms or just use the form id in place of `this`.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="signin(this)">
```

JS:

```
function signin(element) {
 var action = element.form.getAttribute("name");
}
```

or just simply change the `this` to the form's `id` as Lakmal pointed out:

```
function signin() {
 var action = $("#form-signin").attr("name");
}
```